# $V$ as a $HOD$ of its class generic extension

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing, inner-models

By an old result of Roguski, [The theory of the class $HOD$](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0067656), any model $V$ of $ZFC$ has a class generic extension $V[G]$ such that $HOD$ of $V[G]$ equals $V$.
This result is also stated and generalized by Fuchs-Hamkins-Reits in their paper [Set theoretic geology](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168007214001225).

In both of these papers, passing from $V$ to $V[G]$ some cardinals are collapsed. So my question is the following:

> **Question.** Does any model $V$ of $ZFC$ have a cofinality preserving class generic extension $V[G]$ such that $HOD^{V[G]}=V?$

Comment: It seems unlikely that we will be able to answer this, in light of the fact that Foreman's conjecture is open: perhaps every forcing notion either adds a real or collapses a cardinal.  In a model like that, we cannot expect to code sets into HOD by any Ord-length iteration, without collapsing cardinals or adding too many reals.